# summarize from string matches

Tags: r, string, summary

I have this df column:

```
df <- data.frame(Strings = c("ñlas onepojasd", "onenañdsl", "ñelrtwofkld", "asdthreeasp", "asdfetwoasd", "fouroqwke","okasdtwo", "acmofour", "porefour", "okstwo"))
> df
          Strings
1  ñlas onepojasd
2       onenañdsl
3     ñelrtwofkld
4     asdthreeasp
5     asdfetwoasd
6       fouroqwke
7        okasdtwo
8        acmofour
9        porefour
10         okstwo
```

I know that each value from `df$Strings` will match with the words `one, two, three or four`. And I also know that it will match with just ONE of those words. So to match them:

```
str_detect(df$Strings,"one")
str_detect(df$Strings,"two")
str_detect(df$Strings,"three")
str_detect(df$Strings,"four")
```

However, I'm stucked here, as I'm trying to do this table:

```
Homes  Quantity Percent
  One         2     0.3
  Two         4     0.4
Three         1     0.1
 Four         3     0.3
Total        10       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse` and `janitor` you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate(Homes = str_extract(Strings, "one|two|three|four"),
        n = n()) %>%
 group_by(Homes) %>%
 summarise(Quantity = length(Homes),
           Percent = first(length(Homes)/n)) %>%
 adorn_totals("row")

 Homes Quantity Percent
  four        3     0.3
   one        2     0.2
 three        1     0.1
   two        4     0.4
 Total       10     1.0
```

Or with just `tidyverse`:

```
 df %>%
 mutate(Homes = str_extract(Strings, "one|two|three|four"),
        n = n()) %>%
 group_by(Homes) %>%
 summarise(Quantity = length(Homes),
           Percent = first(length(Homes)/n)) %>%
 rbind(., data.frame(Homes = "Total", Quantity = sum(.$Quantity), 
                     Percent = sum(.$Percent)))
```

In both cases the code, first, extracts the matching pattern and count the number of cases. Second, it groups by the matched words. Third, it computes the number of cases per word and the proportion of the given word from all words. Finally, it adds a "Total" row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_extract` and then do the `table` and `prop.table`, i.e.

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(df1$Strings, 'one|two|three|four')
#[1] "one"   "one"   "two"   "three" "two"   "four"  "two"   "four"  "four"  "two"  

table(str_extract(df1$Strings, 'one|two|three|four'))
# four   one three   two 
#    3     2     1     4 

prop.table(table(str_extract(df1$Strings, 'one|two|three|four')))
# four   one three   two 
#  0.3   0.2   0.1   0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` option would be `regmatches/regexpr` with `table`

```
table(regmatches(df$Strings, regexpr('one|two|three|four', df$Strings)))
#  four   one three   two 
#    3     2     1     4
```

adding `addmargins` to get the `sum` and then divide by that

```
out <- addmargins(table(regmatches(df$Strings, 
     regexpr('one|two|three|four', df$Strings))))
out/out[length(out)]

# four   one three   two   Sum 
#  0.3   0.2   0.1   0.4   1.0
```