# str_extract() gives a different result calling a vector from dataframe - R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have this vector:

```
x <- c("De 1 a 2 semanas", "De 3 a 4 semanas", "Más de 6 semanas", "Menos de 1 semana")
```

And I'm trying to extract each value by an unique identity:

```
str_extract(x, "1 sem|1 a 2|3 a 4|5 a 6|de 6 sem")
```

And it works:

```
[1] "1 a 2"    "3 a 4"    "de 6 sem" "1 sem"
```

However, when I call the vector from the dataframe:

```
> x$PVS9
[1] "De 1 a 2 semanas"  "De 3 a 4 semanas"  "Más de 6 semanas"  "Menos de 1 semana"
> x$PVS9 <- str_extract(x$PVS9, "1 sem|1 a 2|3 a 4|5 a 6|de 6 sem")
> x$PVS9
[1] "1 a 2" NA      NA      "1 sem"
```

Why is it giving those two `NA`?

PS: You could find useful this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54787651/summarize-from-string-matches/54788478) (and its answer).

Here is the minimal reproducible example:

```
> dput(x)
structure(list(PVS9 = c("De 1 a 2 semanas", "De 3 a 4 semanas", 
"Más de 6 semanas", "Menos de 1 semana"), n = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L
), Porcentaje = c(0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Current Output:

```
> str_extract(x$PVS9, "1 sem|1 a 2|3 a 4|5 a 6|de 6 sem")
[1] "1 a 2" NA      NA      "1 sem"
```

Desired output:

```
[1] "1 a 2"    "3 a 4"    "de 6 sem" "1 sem"
```

**Additional information:**

Session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Chile.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Chile.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Chile.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Spanish_Chile.1252
```

Class:

```
> class(x$PVS9)
[1] "character"
```

Encoding:

```
> Encoding(x$PVS9)
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"

> guess_encoding(x$PVS9)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  encoding   confidence
  <chr>           <dbl>
1 ISO-8859-1       0.98
2 ISO-8859-2       0.88
3 ISO-8859-9       0.33
```

Also:

```
> x$PVS9 == y
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

I was thinking solving this changuing the encodings of the vector. Is this possible? If not, is there another way?

**EDIT:** More additional information asked.

What R think it is:

```
> sapply(x$PVS9, charToRaw)
$`De 1 a 2 semanas`
 [1] 44 65 20 31 20 61 20 32 20 73 65 6d 61 6e 61 73

$`De 3 a 4 semanas`
 [1] 44 65 20 33 a0 61 20 34 a0 73 65 6d 61 6e 61 73

$`Más de 6 semanas`
 [1] 4d e1 73 20 64 65 20 36 a0 73 65 6d 61 6e 61 73

$`Menos de 1 semana`
 [1] 4d 65 6e 6f 73 20 64 65 20 31 20 73 65 6d 61 6e 61
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it `x <- data.frame(PVS9  = c("De 1 a 2 semanas", "De 3 a 4 semanas", "Más de 6 semanas", 
 "Menos de 1 semana"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE); str_extract(x$PVS9, "1 sem|1 a 2|3 a 4|5 a 6|de 6 sem")
#[1] "1 a 2"    "3 a 4"    "de 6 sem" "1 sem" `

Comment: I cannot either. Paste a minimal x data frame please, see [MCVE].

Comment: specifically, `dput(x)` instead of `dput(x$PVS9)`

Comment: @akrun I just added the full minimal reproducible example `dput(x)`. @divibisan It's a kind of a repost, as I added various new information (but I forgot to put the full example, but I just did it). Hope you can help me, I have been struggling with this for a week almost.

Comment: Thanks. Again, I can't reproduce it which means it's almost certainly something to do with text encoding or locale. Can you try running `sapply(x$PVS9, charToRaw)` - this will convert the strings to raw bytes so we can see _exactly_ what R thinks it has

Comment: @divibisan done. Can you explain a little bit how can you interpret the "thinking" of R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least part of the problem is due to the presence of strange characters that look the same as normal characters to humans, but are different to the computer:

The `charToRaw` converts a character string into the raw hexadecimal values that represent the characters to the computer. Let's take a look at the 2nd string which didn't match for you and compare it to what I see on my computer (where it *does* match):

```
#  This does NOT match
$`De 3 a 4 semanas`
 [1] 44 65 20 33 a0 61 20 34 a0 73 65 6d 61 6e 61 73

# This does match
$`De 3 a 4 semanas`
 [1] 44 65 20 33 20 61 20 34 20 73 65 6d 61 6e 61 73
```

There is a difference: the 5th and 9th numbers are `20` on my system and `a0` on yours. What does that mean? You can use the `intToUtf8` to see how those characters render, though first we have to [convert from hexidecimal to decimal](http://hextodecimal.com):

```
# 20 in hexidecimal
# is 32 in decimal
intToUtf8(32)
[1] " "


# a0 in hexidecimal
# is 160 in decimal
intToUtf8(160)
[1] " "
```

So they both look like spaces to us, but to the computer they're totally different characters. If you look these numbers up on on a [UTF-8 lookup table](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec), you'll see that 32 is a normal space and 160 is a no-break space:

```
32  SPACE
160 NO-BREAK SPACE
```

Non-breaking spaces (aka `&nbsp`) are often found in HTML documents to create wider spaces that (as multiple consecutive normal spaces are shortened to just one).

---

So, how can we fix this? First, let's reproduce your data:

```
bad_str2 <- paste0('De 3', intToUtf8(160), 'a', intToUtf8(160), '4 semanas')

# Looks the same
bad_str2
[1] "De 3 a 4 semanas"

# But has the non-breaking spaces
charToRaw(bad_str2)
 [1] 44 65 20 33 c2 a0 61 c2 a0 34 20 73 65 6d 61 6e 61 73

# Regex does not work:
str_extract(bad_str2, "1 sem|1 a 2|3 a 4|5 a 6|de 6 sem")
[1] NA
```

Now, we can use `gsub` to replace the non-breaking spaces with regular spaces:

```
# The \u prefix means interpret the following Hexidecimal code as a character
# So \ua0 means, the character specified by hex code 'a0', which is the nbsp
fixed_str <- gsub("\ua0", " ", bad_str2, fixed = TRUE)

# Still looks the same
fixed_str
[1] "De 3 a 4 semanas"

# But regex works now!
str_extract(fixed_str, "1 sem|1 a 2|3 a 4|5 a 6|de 6 sem")
[1] "3 a 4"
```

Comment: Excellent! Do you have any reference links to go deeper on this? Because that `x$PVS9` is given (I don't create it). So I would like to make some kind of model to evaluate the data before doing the data processing, but for that I need to understand this matter way better.

Comment: No specific links, I just had a idea what the problem might be since I've run into it before. If you're interested in learning more, you should read about Text Encoding and the UTF-8 standard. Non-breaking spaces are the worst offenders, so if you use `gsub` to clear them from your data that might be enough.